# usage of the conjunction "nor"

Tags: word-usage

Cooking quickly doesn't mean omitting flavor, nor does fast food have to be junk food.

I can't understand this sentence. "nor" is tentative for me to understand.
Can I understand it this way: 
"It doesn't mean fast food have to be junk food."?

Comment: *Cooking fastly* is not English.

Comment: I editted. Cooking quickly

Answer (score -1):

It is a coordination of two main clauses:

*Cooking quickly doesn't mean omitting flavor.*

and

*Fast food doesn't have to be junk food.*

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, since you have changed the sentence structure around.  The first clause is explicitly a negation of something. "Cooking DOES NOT mean omitting flavor."  While the second clause following "nor" is implicitly negated, as the rewording by DW256 demonstrates. "Nor" is what negates the second clause.

Comment: @lumbrjak thank you.